# The relation between copula and survival copula

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival, nonparametric, copula, association-measure

There are two relations connect between *copula* *distribution function* and copula survival function I got confused between them

$¯C(u,v)= u + v -1 + C(1-u,1-v)$
$C(u,v)= 1 - ¯C(1-u) - ¯C(1-v) + ¯C(1-u,1-v)$

So if we have copula function we can find *survival copula*

If you provide some useful references or explanation through an example that illustrates the relation further

Comment: ¯C(u,v) : survival copula ,; C(u,v): copula function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivation of survival copula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485332/derivation-of-survival-copula)